# How to do multiple page scraping using Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

```
#----\
#-----*-----\
#----/       \ 
              \
#----\         \
#-----*-------- *  <-- START
#----/         /
              / 
#----\       /
#-----*-----/     
#----/
```

Here is a structure of a website I want to scrap with scrapy, where * is a page and --- indicates link. I want to scrape data of # pages. 
I have already done a scraper which can scrape data from a single # page.

```
import scrapy


class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    topic = scrapy.Field()
    symptoms = scrapy.Field()


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medical"

    allowed_domains = ['medlineplus.gov']
    start_urls = ['https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000178.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyItem()

        item["topic"] = response.css('h1.with-also::text').extract_first()
        item["symptoms"] = response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()

        yield item
```

The starting webpage is `https://medlineplus.gov/encyclopedia.html`
I want to scrape info about all diseases in the encyclopedia.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to start with the "encyclopedia.html" page, follow the "alpha" links (the A-Z articles links), then, for every followed page, follow the links to the articles.

You can do this with a [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) and the [Link Extractors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html), but, since the crawling depth is small, we can do this with a regular `Spider`:

```
from urlparse import urljoin  # Python 2 only

import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    topic = scrapy.Field()
    symptoms = scrapy.Field()


class MedicalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medical"

    allowed_domains = ['medlineplus.gov']
    start_urls = ['https://medlineplus.gov/encyclopedia.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css("ul.alpha-links li a::attr(href)").extract():
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link), callback=self.parse_alpha_page)

    def parse_alpha_page(self, response):
        for link in response.css("ul#index li a::attr(href)").extract():
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link), callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = MyItem()

        item["topic"] = response.css('h1.with-also::text').extract_first()
        item["symptoms"] = response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()

        yield item
```

Note that it looks like there is a better way to get the desired data from the MedlinePlus (check out the ["For Developers" page](https://medlineplus.gov/fordevelopers.html)).

Comment: thank you! Now I have understood how to use callback. There are explanations in many documents but this clarified my doubt in one shot. By the way since I am new to scrapy are there any good websites/tutorials for scrapy with good examples and explanation? It will help a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShubhamB. sure, there is a lot of information and tutorials on the web - the official tutorial in the scrapy docs is quite detailed. Or, there is that newcoder.io's tutorial (http://newcoder.io/Intro-Scrape/). Another good way to improve your scrapy skills is to go over the [most voted scrapy questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy?sort=votes&pageSize=10). Thanks.